# Deleting a table having column having ENUM type in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table in sqlalchemy on postgres database. It has a column that is dependent on `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM`. When I try to delete the table, I get an error.
`DETAIL:  column my_column of table myTable depends on type my_enum HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.`
Why do I get this error and how to fix this?

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM
mt = MetaData()
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://localhost:5555/postgres')
mt.bind = engine
_type = ENUM('a', 'b', name = 'my_enum')
t = Table('myTable', mt, Column('my_column', _type))
t.create()
t.drop()
```

Comment: I am using version 1.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ENUM type is deleted along with table. To prevent it from happening, it must be associated with the metadata object rather. So, changing the line

`_type = ENUM('a', 'b', name = 'my_enum', metadata = mt)`

solves the problem.

For more details, refer https://www.kite.com/python/docs/sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM